# heading on multiple page by awk

Tags: awk

We all familiar with `awk 'BEGIN {action} condition {action} END {action}'`. But I can only use it to make a heading on page one. If I have output of multiple page how can I get a heading, page no& foot note on each page after 72 records? It is presumed that each page can contains 72 lines.

Comment: I think `pr` command would be better suited for this..

Comment: I used pr in past but problem is that we can not print data like total at end of page. Whether it is possible please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know how many records:

```
awk 'BEGIN { /* print initial header */ } 
     (NR - 1) % 72 == 0 { /* print footer; print next page header */}
     { /* action */ } 
     END { /* print footer */ }' /path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks ikkachu. But when I use (NR-1) %72 it print heading & footer only and print data with header & footer. So I used NR%72 and its work. But now want ask that whether it is possible to print page total and cumulative  total  at end of each page.